# VBA msgbox in Form code, get variable from Module sub

Tags: vba, module, userform

In the USER FORM code, after the user has clicked "OK," there is a msgbox
ie. `MsgBox ("The total price is " & Price & "")`

The thing is, I've calculated the Price variable in a MODULE sub.

How can I ensure the price value actually shows up? How do I connect a variable from a module sub to a form?

To be more general, how can I make a message box to show up after that the user clicked "OK". Do I need to have two message boxes within my code?

Code Sample:

In Module:

```
Dim Price As Currency

Sub Test1()
    Price = wsSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Value
End Sub
```

In Form:

```
Sub cmdOK_click
   MsgBox ("The total price is " & Price & "")
End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: I would make the `Test1` a `Public Sub` and also call it on the condition that user clicks `OK`. That's an idea and actually it's too late for me to check it. But let us know if that would work for you.

Comment: is `Test1()` Sub called within the same `Sub` that calls the User Form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All indicates you are not calling the `Sub` where you perform the `Price` calculation. I Suggest you to do like this:

In your module:

```
Public Price As Currency

Sub Test1()

    Price = wsSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Value

End Sub
```

In your Userform code:

```
Private Sub cmdOK_click()

    Call Test1
    MsgBox ("The total price is " & Price & "")

End Sub
```

If your plans for the code allows, you can also make the `MsgBox` shows up in the module instead. So you'd have something like this:

In your module:

```
Public Price As Currency

Sub Test1()

    Price = wsSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Value
    MsgBox ("The total price is " & Price & "")

End Sub
```

In your Userform code:

```
Private Sub cmdOK_click()

    Call Test1

End Sub
```

Please, let me know if it helps you or not properly.